# Button mashing game error

Tags: python, windows-7

A few days ago, I requested a working method so that by the end of a time limit it automatically ends the input. I was given this code but I can't make it work.

```
print("Go!")

def check():
    import time
    from threading import Thread
    answer=input()
    answer = None
    time.sleep(9.58)
    if answer != None:
        return
        distance=answer.count
        print ("And he crosses the line with...",distance)
    Thread(target = check).start()

    answer = input("1")
check()
```

The idea of the game is button mashing.

Comment: No code will execute after `return` is encountered

Comment: What are you tring to achieve with answer=input()
    answer = None?

Comment: why threading?! why you did not use while?